# There's no console output for some reason (double and float data types C#)?

Tags: c#, double, pi

```
namespace Floatandouble
 {
class Program
 {
    static void Main string[] args)
     {

        float floatPI = 3.141592653589793238f;
        double DoublePI = 3.141592653589793238;

        Console.WriteLine("Float PI is: " + floatPI);
        Console.WriteLine("Double PI is: " + DoublePI);
    }
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

 }
```

I'm just trying to work on my basics (Real floating point types) for C# as I'm new to this language. I'm pretty sure my code is correct, however, there are many errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That code wont even compile, `Console.Readline()` is not inside `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

the only prroblem your code has is that you are putting Console.ReadLine() inside the class, you should put it inside Main function.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float floatPI = 3.141592653589793238f;
            double DoublePI = 3.141592653589793238;

            Console.WriteLine("Float PI is: " + floatPI);
            Console.WriteLine("Double PI is: " + DoublePI);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```